# If date is between conditional

Tags: datetime, conditional

I want to check if it's winter. What is the best way to write a "between dates" conditional?

```
{% set saison = now|date('m-d') %}
{% if saison (saison >= '11-22' and saison <= '03-21') %}
  Jep it's winter
{% endif %}
```

This absolutely does not work.
I also tried somthing like:

```
{% set saison = now|date('m-d') %}
{% if saison > '03-21' %}
  Now it's Spring
{% elseif saison > '06-21' %}
  Now it's Summer
{% elseif saison > '09-23' %}
  Now it's Fall
{% elseif saison > '12-22' %}
  Now it's Winter
{% endif %}
```

That doesn't work. I guess because twig doesn't recognize the strings as dates?
How do I have to write this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This conditional should work:

```
{# Saison Trigger #}
{% set saison = now|date('m-d') %}

{# Check for each Season #}
{% if saison > '11-22' or saison <= '03-21' %}
    {% set currentSaison = 'winter' %}
{% elseif saison > '03-21' and saison <= '06-21' %}
    {% set currentSaison = 'fruehling' %}
{% elseif saison > '06-21' and saison <= '09-22' %}
    {% set currentSaison = 'sommer' %}
{% elseif saison > '09-22' and saison <= '11-22' %}
    {% set currentSaison = 'herbst' %}
{% endif %}
```

You're right, Twig does just compare the strings. But this is totally fine in this case. A string representing a date and formatted like so "01-13" (don't forget the leading zero) works nicely with the comparison operators.